# Google api schema for user fields

Tags: google-provisioning-api

I have created a software that connects to Google apps email and allows me to create a signature for specified users with their info. In Google apps domain management is no possibility to edit more "advanced" fields like company address, fax, emails, title, nickname etc.. so I used Flash Panel which offer me this possibility. But for this I need the fields api schema to add it in my config in order to connect Google fields with my merge fields. I have managed to make it work for some fields like: Name, Company name, email address, all types of phones, title, department, manager, fax number by adding the following in my config file:

```
<string>name=Name.FullName</string>
<string>company=Organizations[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work].Name</string>
<string>mail=PrimaryEmail.Address</string>
<string>mobile=Phonenumbers[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile].Value</string>
<string>title=Organizations[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work].Title</string>
<string>department=Organizations[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work].Department</string>
<string>managerGA=ContactEntry.Relations[Rel:manager].Value</string>
<string>phone number=Phonenumbers[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work_fax].Value</string>
<string>emlHome=Emails[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home].Address</string>
or
<string>homeEml=Emails[Home:true].Address</string>
```

What is before "=" its just a name used for the connection and what I need is what is after the "="..

I have searched through Google documentation but I didn't managed to find the correct api schema format for some fields like: country, city, street, nickname, photo, website, URL, Notes, Organization Unit, Aka, and any others. Also in Flash Panel there is a possibility to add custom fields and would be great if I could connect those too with the merge fields from my signature template editor. Can someone help me with the correct ones or where/how can I find them?

Also for example if a user has two home emails, I know how to retrieve the first one, but how should the string look like for the second one?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old unanswered question that I found in passing.

The example uses the Profiles API which was deprecated in December 2013. See the migration guide: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/migrate

As of 2016, the API is the User resource of the Admin SDK. The API docs are here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update

You can use `User.primaryEmail` for the Google Apps account's id/address and you can iterate through the array of `User.emails[]` for any additional email addresses.